# Can items of DataGridViewComboBoxColumn be of custom object type?

Tags: .net, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

In a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` I need to use values of my class `MyValue` as combo box items (in `Items` property), but I am getting a **DataError** during the runtime when leaving the combobox column in which I selected any of my values.

How can be DataGridViewComboBoxColumn used with values of custom type (without DataError errors)?

---

More details:

Class `MyValue` looks like this:

```vb
Public Class MyValue
    Implements ICloneable
    Public Property Definition As String
    Public Shadows Function ToString() As String
        Return "DEF" & Definition
    End Function
    Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
        Return MemberwiseClone()
    End Function
End Class
```

The `DataSource` property is not set and is expected **not** to be mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with DataError are present until given `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` has properties `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` empty.

- Set `DisplayMember` to name of property which can serve as displayed value.
- Set `ValueMember` to name of property which can serve to identify the value object.

Note that with unbound column they cannot be set in designer, because it reverts them back to `""`, so they have to be set programmatically.

Example:

```vb
DisplayMember = "Definition"
ValueMember = "ThisObject"
```

...with self-referencing property `ThisObject` added into the `MyValue` class:

```vb
Public Class MyValue
    '...
    Public Property ThisObject As MyValue
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        ThisObject = Me
    End Sub
    '...
End Class
```